# declare variable in python ctypes and passing to dll function

Tags: c++, python-2.7, ctypes

for example I have a C++ variable declaration and function like this(assume its a dll function)

```
    int img_width, img_height, stride;
    somefunction(&img_width, &img_height, &stride)
    {
    ....
    }
```

same thing how can we do using python ctypes?

I tried in the following way

```
img_width, img_height, stride = c.POINTER(c_int), c.POINTER(c_int), c.POINTER(c_int)
dll.somefunction(img_width, img_height, stride)
```

which resulted the following exception

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: : Don't know how to convert parameter 1)
```

I also tried in following way

```
dll.somefunction.restype = c.c_void_p
dll.somefunction.argtypes = [c.POINTER(c_int), c.POINTER(c_int), c.POINTER(c_int)]
dll.somefunction(img_width, img_height, stride)
```

Where I endup with following exception

```
NameError: global name 'img_width' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating types where you need to create instances of the integers and pass by reference:

```
from ctypes import *

# Declare the argument types
dll.somefunction.argtypes = POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int)

# Create instances of the types needed
img_width, img_height, stride = c_int(), c_int(), c_int()

# Pass by reference
dll.somefunction(byref(img_width), byref(img_height), byref(stride))
```

Comment: Is the question not ‘how to change a c variable from python’, rather than how to change a ‘python variable in c’. I think he wants to change the c instance of img_width from python. I have a similar problem. I want to set a c char **pointer, called results,  in python. I want to set results so that it ‘points’ to a string in python. . I want to get the string I created in python, (or at least a copy of it since ctypes doeds a lot of copying), to be pointed to by the c variable results.   So I have python product_class =  (ctypes.c_char_p)(b"321").  I want to set results with the value “321”.

Comment: @drlolly OP accepted it, so it does what they want.  Ask your own question (not a comment) and I'd be glad to answer it.

Comment: Here is my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75322024/how-set-a-c-char-pointer-in-python